# Sidebar typo - can we fix this?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, asking-questions

I was about to post a question, when I noticed the sidebar:

[image: sidebar]

Shouldn't that be *programming puzzle**s** or code golf*

Answer (score 8):

The following is now live:

> [image: no grammer miss-steaks hear]

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, it should.

This is the same text that is used in several other places on the site:

---

[image]

*What's your $TOPIC$ question?*

---

[image]

[*rather than discussing $TOPIC$ itself.*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

---

[image]

[*...are not about $TOPIC$ as defined in the help center.*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

---

I have to go right now, but when I have time I'll poke someone and ask to fix it (probably by adding an *s*).